# How to avoid randomly displayed elements in pagination Flask?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I've come across a weird problem. The question is, why using following code, I can see the same CVE on 2 or even 3 different pages? It looks like every page, has randomly displayed CVE codes, yet descending, just like I have specified in code. And also every time when I click on "All Entries", cve codes are changing, just like on screenshots below. Any ideas? What's causing that problem?

**page 1**
[image: page 1]

**same 1st page after clicking "All entries" again**
[image: same 1st page after clicking "All entries" again]

And it keeps changing every time I enter this page, or even switch one page back or further.

**Also worth to mention, something like that doesn't happen when keyword is specified, after running different query.**

**views.py**

```
@main.route('/cve_list', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def cve_list():
    search_form = SearchForm()
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    cve = Cve.query.order_by(Cve.date.desc()).paginate(page=page, per_page=5)
    value = request.args.get('search')
    if value:
        query = Cve.query.filter(Cve.content.contains(f'{value}')).order_by(Cve.date.desc())
        page_search = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
        paginated_query = query.paginate(page=page_search, per_page=5)
        cve_amount = Cve.query.filter(Cve.content.contains(f'{value}')).count()
        return render_template('cve_list.html',
                               title='Cve List',
                               form=search_form,
                               cve=paginated_query,
                               value=value)
    return render_template('cve_list.html',
                           title='Cve List',
                           form=search_form,
                           cve=cve)
```

**html**

```
  {% for page_num in cve.iter_pages(left_edge=1, right_edge=1, left_current=2, right_current=4) %}
        {% if page_num %}
            {% if cve.page == page_num %}
                <a class="btn btn-info mb-4" href="{{ url_for('main.cve_list', search=value, page=page_num) }}">{{ page_num }}</a>
            {% else %}
                <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="{{ url_for('main.cve_list', search=value, page=page_num) }}">{{ page_num }}</a>
            {% endif %}
        {% else %}
        {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
```

**models.py**

```
class Cve(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True, nullable=False)
    content = db.Column(db.Text, unique=True, nullable=False)
    date = db.Column(db.String(40), unique=False, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"CVE('{self.title}'), ('{self.content}'), ('{self.date}')"
```

Comment: We'll need to see more information about your `Cve` model, please add enough detail about that model to your question to let us reproduce this issue. **At a guess** ordering just by date is not enough, you'll need to add another column to your ordering for there to be a stable ordering of your query results.

Comment: Ok, I've added Cve model to the post.

Comment: Note that the pagination object already has a `.total` attribute, you don't need to make a separate `.count()` query just to get the total number of matching elements from your query.

Comment: Wow, didn't know about that. I think the problem is that those Cve codes might have exactly the same date, thats why maybe theyre being displayed randomly, yet descending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your results are not unique within each date; the database is not required to return results *within the same date* in the same order each time. You need to add another column into the `ORDER BY` that produces a stable order.

Here, that could be the `id` column, because it is unique (every result will have a different ID) and the values have a stable order (it's an integer, integers have a specific  set order):

```
cve = Cve.query.order_by(Cve.date.desc(), Cve.id.asc()).paginate(page=page, per_page=5)
```

Note that your code can be much simpler. There is no need to re-read the `page` request variable, and you don't need to create two separate paths for the *search text* and *no search text* variants. You also don't make full use of the `SearchForm()` object.

SQLAlchemy query objects can be refined dynamically; `Cve.query` gives you a [`Query` instance](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query), but **so does [`Query.filter()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter)**. Anything you can do to the original `Cve.query` object you *also* could do to the result of `Query.filter()`. So do this:

```
@main.route('/cve_list', methods=['GET'])
def cve_list():
    # base query, all the CVEs
    query = Cve.query

    search_form = SearchForm(request.args)
    if search_form.validate():
        value = search_form.value.data
        if value:
            # limit the query to items that contain the search string
            query = query.filter(Cve.content.contains(value))

    # apply ordering and pagination
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    # query can be *all* CVEs, or only those that match the search value!
    ordered = query.order_by(Cve.date.desc(), Cve.id.asc())
    paginated_query = ordered.paginate(page=page_search, per_page=5)

    return render_template(
        'cve_list.html',
        title='Cve List',
        form=search_form,
        cve=paginated_query,
    )
```

- There is no need to add a separate `.count()` query either, just use the [`.total` attribute on the `Pagination` object](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/api/#flask_sqlalchemy.Pagination.total).
- Your code only ever looks for URL parameters, so it doesn't need to handle POST requests. I limited the view to only accept `GET`.
- You defined a search form, but didn't use it in your view. Let the form verify that data was entered. In an optional search form that is perhaps not as important, but you want to use `validate()` anyway because that way, if you decide to extend the form, you already have the validation step in place.

  At the very least, by creating the form *from `request.args`, you now have a form object with the `value` string already connected to the right form element. Rendering the form will give you the right value in the text box now.

Comment: Solved! :-) That was the issue, ordering by both, date and id was the case. Thank you so much sir! It's ridicolous how much you can learn from somebody more experienced in less than 5 minutes.